# 2 Different Nav Menus Have Same Name in WP-Admin

Tags: menus

The following code is producing 2x menus with identical names.
Why is the second-menu name "Primary Navigation" in the screenshot below? I would expect it to be "Single-Page Navigation"

```
  register_nav_menus([
    'primary_navigation' => __('Primary Navigation', 'sage'),
    'single_page_navigation' => __('Single-Page Navigation', 'sage'),
  ]);
```

[image]

Comment: Does the issue still occur if you don't use the translation functions? So that'd be just `'Single-Page Navigation'` instead of `__('Single-Page Navigation', 'sage')`.

Comment: Bingo, thanks @JacobPeattie! Hadn't seen that symptom before :)